# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of null

Tags: jquery, ajax

**This error comes out when the post request does not return records**

```
var idgood=$('#good').val();
table = $('#alldata').DataTable({
    "responsive": true,
    "bDestroy": true,
    "bDeferRender": true,
    "aProcessing": true,
    "aServerSide": true,
    "ajax":{
        url: "src/design/controllers/processor.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {"action": "list","id": idgood},
    },
    "aoColumns": [
            { 'mData': 'id',"visible":false },
            { 'mData': 'typevalue'},
            { 'mData': 'moneyvalue'},
            { 'mData': 'unitedvalue' },
            { 'mData': 'value' }
    ],
    "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
    "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
    language: {"url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Spanish.json"},
    "bInfo": false,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "searching": false
});
```

When the post request returns records I don't get errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't handle your ajax request output at all. Ajax request should have post-actions like `success` , `done` , `fail`.

You try to assign the values coming from your back-end and works when you have data but you don't handle the case that there is no data.

You need something like:

```
let request = $.ajax({
    url: "src/design/controllers/processor.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {"action": "list","id": idgood},
});

request.sucess(function(output) {
  //assign your values to a variable which will be inserted in your DataTable
});

request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

Keep in mind that empty response does not mean that the ajax request failed. So make sure you handle that case in a way that suits your application